# How to add animation for geojson features in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I am trying to add some animation like a fade in and out to my geojson features as seen in leaflet-barchart.js. I managed to toggle my bar charts whereby when the checkbox is checked, the bar charts will appear and vice-versa. The only problem I have right now is to add some animations to the barcharts when appearing. For example, in jquery you can do .show(500) and .hide(500) and the object will slowly appear or disappear. I tried doing mymap.addLayer(IndiaBarChart).show(500) but its not working and Im looking for alternative animation solutions. Since this is a leaflet thing, I think there might be an animation plugin for the layers but I cant find it. If you do know of how to animate the appearance of the bar charts, do let me know. I have the code below but as of now, when I select the checkbox, the bar charts will pop up or disappear immediately.

```
// HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Cdn for Barcharts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-d4jm/DxK0vxzigVql4lmwFikmXIlItcko9Me2md/mwI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-motion.js"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Hides the piechart at the beginning
                if($(".leaflet-piechart-icon")){
                    $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide();
                }
                // Hides the piechart legend at the beginning
                if($(".legend")){
                    $(".legend").hide();
                }
                // Hides the stringlines at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                }
                // Hides the barchart at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(UaeBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                    mymap.removeLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                }
                // Shows or hides layers when checkbox is checked or unchecked
                $('input[id="pie-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").show(500);
                        $(".legend").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide(500);
                        $(".legend").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="bar-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(UaeBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                        mymap.addLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(IndiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(ChinaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(MalaysiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(UaeBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(TaiwanBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(IndonesiaBarChart);
                        mymap.removeLayer(TurkeyBarChart);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="choropleth"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        //$("").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        //$("").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="string-lines"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(polyline);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="pie-charts"> Pie Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bar-charts"> Bar Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="choropleth"> Choropleth
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="string-lines"> String Lines
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-choropleth.js"></script>
        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-barchart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


// leaflet-barchart.js
var options = [{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 22,'dataPoint2': 36,'dataPoint3': 42,'dataPoint4': 20}, // India Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 44,'dataPoint2': 36,'dataPoint3': 28,'dataPoint4': 20}, // China Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 22,'dataPoint2': 36,'dataPoint3': 42,'dataPoint4': 56}, // Taiwan Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 28,'dataPoint2': 33,'dataPoint3': 40,'dataPoint4': 28}, // Malaysia Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 55,'dataPoint2': 54,'dataPoint3': 54,'dataPoint4': 55}, // Indonesia Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 53,'dataPoint2': 40,'dataPoint3': 19,'dataPoint4': 58}, // UAE Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
},{
    data: {'dataPoint1': 32,'dataPoint2': 36,'dataPoint3': 36,'dataPoint4': 40}, // Turkey Bar chart
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
}];
var IndiaBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(20.894, 78.962), options[0]).addTo(mymap);
var ChinaBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(35.861, 104.195), options[1]).addTo(mymap);
var MalaysiaBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(4.21, 101.97), options[2]).addTo(mymap);
var UaeBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(23.421, 53.8478), options[3]).addTo(mymap);
var TaiwanBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(23.6978, 120.9605), options[4]).addTo(mymap);
var IndonesiaBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(0.7892, 113.9213), options[5]).addTo(mymap);
var TurkeyBarChart = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(38.9637, 35.2433), options[6]).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: What kind of animation? Are you referring to a "fade in" / "fade out" change in opacity? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: You say "as seen in leaflet-barchart.js". What *exactly* is "leaflet-barchart.js", where can people like me find that?

Comment: @IvanSanchez leaflet-barchart.js is a js file I created, the code of leaflet-barchart.js is in the post. That was how I created the bar charts in leaflet

Comment: @IvanSanchez Do you know of a way to do the animations? Like .show(500) and .hide(500) Please help me out I really have difficulties doing this.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Hi Ivan, are u there?